# how to fill a <td> with an image inside a table?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a table inside a table and I want my images inside the  to fill the entire  but not the entire table.

Here is an image of what I have: [image]

> **Note**: I want each image to cover the entire blue space

I don't want it to look like this: [image]

Here is my css:

```css
    .table {
   
        color:#000;
        width:100%;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .table tr {
        background-color: none;
        }
        .table td {
        font-size:15px;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding:15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        text-align: center;
        }
        .header1 {
        font-size:1em;
        color:#000;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
    <table class="table" border="1">
    <td>
    <table>
               <td><img src="http://januarymay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/t-shirt2.jpg" alt="Tshirt model" height="100%" width="100%"></td>
               <td><img src="http://januarymay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/t-shirt2.jpg" alt="Tshirt model" height="100%" width="100%"></td>
               <tr>
               <td><img src="http://januarymay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/t-shirt2.jpg" alt="Tshirt model" height="100%" width="100%"></td>
               <td><img src="http://januarymay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/t-shirt2.jpg" alt="Tshirt model" height="100%" width="100%"></td>
               </tr>
               </table>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <h1 class="header1">AX Squares Tshirt</h1>
    <p>Favorite tshirt with graphics designed by the man. Heather gray. 100% Cotton.<p>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="R4HBCYS75M7P2">
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose your size:">Choose your size:</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
     <option value="Small">Small $25.00 USD</option>
     <option value="Medium">Medium $25.00 USD</option>
     <option value="Large">Large $25.00 USD</option>
     <option value="XL">XL $25.00 USD</option>
    </select> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    
    
    </td>
    </table>
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Et9Ku/)

Comment: So you want it to cover entire cell but not to look like the second screenshot?

Comment: since this isnt tabular data a more flexible implementation would be to use DIVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect, tables structure look like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You are missing the rows multiple times, this would give you undesired results

Answer (score 1):

Your `.table td` has a `padding:15px;` - remove it and image will take the entire cell

Comment: That does what I said I don't want to do in the second image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to fill the entire cell, remove the padding from `.table td`

Comment: That does what I said I don't want to do in the second image.

Comment: Move the padding to the `.table`, But fix your html too to be valid.